# Add-On Dev: Access Property Details

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties

This question has likely been asked before. I tried to search, but I honestly don't know how to phrase the question specifically enough to find anything.

If I define a property inside of a class like this:

```
class Type(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    stuff : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Property Name",
        description="Property Info",
        default=False,
        )
```

Is it possible to access the **name**, **description**, **default**, and other fields, later at execution time? Say, for example, during a panel draw function?

**Edit**:

After posting, I starting playing around and found that `class_instance.__annotations__.values()` seems to include all of this data. But I'm not sure how to sort it out or access the data. I'm still pretty unskilled with Python concepts like tuples and dictionaries, but it looks like the wanted data may be in a dictionary? I'm thinking it may be possible to access it with something like `var.__annotations__.values()[1]['description']`.

But even if something like this is possible, would it be the correct way to do it? Is there a better way?

Comment: `annotations` is a new stuff in Python3. Which Blender 2.80 adapt the feature to make those properties as **annotations**. And you can use `__annotations__` to access those data for sure. If the value is not modified since the Group created, those properties can only be access in **annotations** AFAIK. But maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access them through RNA without using annotations. Assuming you have registered your `PropertyGroup` you can access them like in the following example.

For instance the code below gives you access to the description of Eevee's render samples property.

```
bpy.context.scene.eevee.bl_rna.properties["taa_render_samples"].description
```

Comment: Thanks! Are `bl_rna.properties` and `__annotations__` similar features? I don't entirely understand what sets these apart. One thing I noticed was that `__annotations__` only seems to include "properties", where `bl_rna.properties` seems to include all members? Is that true? Are there any other differences?

Comment: After looking a little deeper, `__annotations__` looks to primarily be groupings of strings, where `bl_rna.properties` looks more like a class instance with many property details, some of which are also strings. I think I'm starting to get it.

Comment: The `__annotations__` are relevant for the declaration of the properties using the `:` syntax. It allows you to access the class variables like a dictionary. It usually becomes relevant  when you want to create properties dynamically (which you don't do in your example). I haven't checked Blender's source code for this, but I'm fairly certain that `bl_rna.properties` uses these annotations under the hood. If the properties are registered I find the approach through the Blender API a bit nicer.